# Chain Scala Futures return type

Tags: scala, future

I am trying to chain Futures in Scala but it is giving me the wrong return type.

I have the following methods:

```
  def getOneRecordByModel(x:DirectFlight): Future[Option[FlightByDetailModel]] = {
    select.allowFiltering().where(_.from eqs x.from).and(_.to eqs x.to).and(_.departure eqs x.departure).and(_.arrival eqs x.arrival).and(_.carrier eqs x.airline).and(_.code eqs x.flightCode).one()
  }
  def getRecordByUUID(x:FlightByDetailModel): Future[Option[FlightByUUIDModel]] = {
    select.allowFiltering().where(_.uuid eqs x.uuid).one()
  }

  def getUUIDRecordByModel(x:DirectFlight): Future[Option[FlightByUUIDModel]] = {
      getOneRecordByModel(x) andThen {
        case Success(Some(flight)) => getRecordByUUID(flight)
        case Success(x) => Success(x)
        case Failure(x) => Failure(x)
      }
    }
```

But now I get the error that the `getUUIDRecordByModel` return type is `Future[Option[FlightByDetailModel]]`

How do I chain them correctly?

Comment: When you use andThen you don't change the return type. You want flatMap or map depending on the return type of the other method.

Comment: The `andThen` combinator is purely meant for side effecting.  It always returns the `Future` that it is being called on, unchanged.  As mentioned by the others, `map` and/or `flatMap` should be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use `flatMap` instead.

```
def getUUIDRecordByModel(x:DirectFlight): Future[Option[FlightByUUIDModel]] = {
    getOneRecordByModel(x) flatMap {
        case Some(flight) => getRecordByUUID(flight)
        case None => Future.successful(None)
    }
}
```

`andThen` applies a side-effecting function and returns the *original* `Future`, not the inner one.

Answer (score 5):

This solution and the 2 above it, are effectively the same. They suggest the simple answer of composition of flatMaps.  This is good for one-off solutions.

```
for {
   oUuid <- getOneRecordByModel(x)
   oFlight <- oUuid.map(getRecordByUUID).getOrElse(Future.successful(None))
} yield oFlight
```

I suspect given the method signatures, you're going to be using this strategy a lot.  If that's the case, @Eugene Zhulenev's answer above (which is a more functional solution) is recommended.  Thought Monad Transformers can look a bit intimidating at first glance, the chunk of code here:

```
val flightByUUID = for {
  flightByDetailModel <- optionT(getOneRecordByModel(x))
  flightByUUIDModel   <- optionT(getRecordByUUID(flightByDetailModel))
} yield flightByUUIDModel

flightByUUID.run  // this line grabs you a Future[Option[T]]
```

Is very simple, and scalable as you start adding complexity.  Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: works as well thank you very much. Unfortunately I can only select one answer as correct.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it nicely with scalaz monad transformers, optionT more specifically. You can reed nice set of articles, and more specific you need this one: http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monad+transformers.html#Monad+transformers

This one is good to: http://noelwelsh.com/programming/2013/12/20/scalaz-monad-transformers/

```
def getOneRecordByModel(x:DirectFlight): Future[Option[FlightByDetailModel]] = ???
  def getRecordByUUID(x:FlightByDetailModel): Future[Option[FlightByUUIDModel]] = ???

  def getUUIDRecordByModel(x:DirectFlight): Future[Option[FlightByUUIDModel]] = {
    import scalaz.OptionT._

    val flightByUUID = for {
      flightByDetailModel <- optionT(getOneRecordByModel(x))
      flightByUUIDModel <- optionT(getRecordByUUID(flightByDetailModel))
    } yield flightByUUIDModel

    flightByUUID.run
  }
```

To be able to use optionT with scala.concurrent.Future you need Functor and Monad instances to be in scope

```
  import scala.concurrent.Future

    object FutureMonadAndFunctor {

    import scalaz.Monad

    implicit def FutureM(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Monad[Future] = new Monad[Future] {
      def point[A](a: => A): Future[A] = Future(a)
      def bind[A, B](fa: Future[A])(f: (A) => Future[B]): Future[B] = fa flatMap f
    }

    implicit def FutureF(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Functor[Future] = new Functor[Future]{
      def map[A, B](fa: Future[A])(f: (A) => B): Future[B] = fa map f
    }
  }

  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  implicit val F = FutureMonadAndFunctor.FutureF
  implicit val M = FutureMonadAndFunctor.FutureM
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I have come across Scalaz multiple times now. I guess it is time for me to do some studying.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to use flatMap for composition instead of andThen, which is rather specialized for dealing with side effects:

```
getOneRecordByModel(x) flatMap { 
    ...
}
```

For working with futures, I found it helpful to read [this page](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) several times.